# terminal command to disable / enable "Automatic Screen Brightness" (Ubuntu 23.10)

Tags: power-management

For convenience's sake, I would like to set keyboard shortcuts to enable / disable "Automatic Screen Brightness" in the Power settings. Do such commands exist?

Comment: like `dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/idle-dim "true"` and `dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/idle-dim "false"` ?

Comment: thanks for your reply!
This does affect the Dim Screen setting. I want the one just above: "Automatic Screen Brightness"
But it does work, so this would be the kind of thing I am looking for

Comment: ... then please add the output of `dconf list /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/`

Comment: ambient-enabled
idle-dim
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
sleep-inactive-ac-type

Comment: I tried dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/ambient-enabled "true" and false and it doesn't seem to change anything. At least it doesn't flick the switch in the graphical power settings menu (whereas it does when I enter the idle-dim command as you suggested).
I also tried
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false
as suggested here:
https://itsfoss.com/automatic-brightness-ubuntu/

But also no noticeable result.

Comment: Then the answer by @GAD3R below should be valid in this case … Although `gsettings` is just a front end for `dconf` but it supports schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn off the automatic brightness (Machines with auto brightness feature support):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false
```

To enable it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled true
```

Comment: This works :)
Funnily enough, it doesn't flick the switch the graphical menu when I enter the command (whereas it does for the idle-dim setting just below that Raffa first suggested). But it works because it doesn't dim the screen anymore when I cover the sensor.